# App.js Navigation error : Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to redirect my current app screen to login screen if the user is not authenticated. So I created a global component `RedirectorToLogin` and use this component in my `App.js` . But I'm getting this error `Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator ?` because I'm using `useNavigation` inside `RedirectorToLogin`.

What is the reason for this error to be occured ?

My RedirectorToLogin.js

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import AuthGlobal from '../Context/store/AuthGlobal'

const RedirectorToLogin = (props) => {
  const context = useContext(AuthGlobal)
  const navigation = useNavigation()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!context.stateUser.isAuthenticated) {
      navigation.navigate('Login')
    }

    return () => {}
  }, [context.stateUser.isAuthenticated])

  return <></>
}

export default RedirectorToLogin
```

My App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar'
import React from 'react'
import { LogBox } from 'react-native'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import Toast from 'react-native-toast-message'
import ErrorBoundary from 'react-native-error-boundary'

// Redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './Redux/store'

// Context API
import Auth from './Context/store/Auth'

// Navigatiors
import Main from './Navigators/Main'

// Screens
import Header from './Shared/Header'
import MyAppState from './Global/MyAppState'
import Network from './Global/Network'
import RedirectorToLogin from './Global/RedirectorToLogin'

const errorHandler = (error, stackTrace) => {
  /* Log the error to an error reporting service */
  console.log('**** error log form error handler ****')
  console.log(error)
  console.log(stackTrace)
  console.log('**** **** ****')
}

LogBox.ignoreAllLogs(true)

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary onError={errorHandler}>
      <Auth>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Header />
            <Main />
            <MyAppState />
            <Network />
            <RedirectorToLogin />
            <Toast ref={(ref) => Toast.setRef(ref)} />
          </NavigationContainer>
        </Provider>
      </Auth>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I referred to [this article](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow#how-it-will-work) and updated my `Main.js` to show only login navigator when user is not authenticated. So I can get rid of having `RedirectorToLogin`